# javax.ws.rs.client.Client definir timeout

Tags: java, cdi

Tenho uma aplicação web onde em um determinado momento faço requisições em um `endpoint` utilizando `JAX-RS RestEasy` da seguinte forma:

```
// Outros códigos acima
@Inject
private Client client;
...

WebTarget webTarget = client.target(URL).path(ENDPOINT);
Response response = webTarget.request().post// continua
```

Até então consigo realizar normalmente o POST, porém, preciso considerar definir o timeout HTTP para essa operação. Pesquisando percebi que o pessoal utiliza o Jersey para realizar a seguinte configuração:

```
client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT,    1000);
```

Eu não utilizo essa dependência no projeto e, apenas por teste, experimentei utilizar e ao rodar a aplicação no Wildfly uma série de exceções e conflitos surgem devido a conflitos com outras dependências necessárias.

Uma observação importante é que o objeto **client** é **injetado via CDI**.

Pois bem, gostaria de saber como eu poderia definir o timeout sem utilizar essa dependência do Jersey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifiquei que não é possível realmente definir valores para timeout quando esse tipo de objeto é injetado.

Como solução alternativa alterei o cliente http para o Apache **org.apache.httpcomponents** e produzo instâncias do seguinte modo:

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(timeout * 1000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout * 1000)
        .setSocketTimeout(timeout * 1000)
        .build();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
```